# Redefine a command together with particular arguments

Tags: renewcommand

For example, I would like to replace all `\hat{N}` by `\widehat{N}`, but leaves `\hat{#1}` unchanged for `#1=`anything else.

I wish to implement it at macro level, and not replacing the text in the document, because these replacements are bind to a particular use of package. I don't want to undo the replacement whenever the corresponding package is not used.

Comment: While this is possible at the macro level, using the editor's search/replace will be much easier.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _other `\hat{}`_. `\let\hat\widehat` would assign `\widehat` to `\hat` meaning from the point of definition onward all `\hat` would act as `\widehat` until the end of a document or the next re-definition. You can narrow this effect to a group, e.g. `{\let\hat\widehat ...}`

Comment: @campa Yes, at Macro level, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Celdor Thanks, I update the question a little and hope it makes it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* want to do it. Notwithstanding that a respected user recommended it, it's not right (at least in my opinion).

Anyway, you can redefine `\hat` to look for its argument and see whether

1. it's more than one token (use `\widehat`)
2. it's a single uppercase Latin letter (use `\widehat`)
3. it's a single command denoting an uppercase Greek letter (use `\widehat`)

In all other cases use `\hat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathhat}{\hat}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\hat}{m}
 {
  \joeli_hat:n { #1 }
 }

\clist_const:Nn \c__joeli_hat_greek_clist
 {
  \Gamma,\Delta,\Theta,\Kappa,\Lambda,\Xi,\Pi,\Sigma,\Upsilon,\Phi,\Omega
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joeli_hat:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {% just one token
    \__joeli_hat_single:N #1
   }
   {
    \widehat{#1}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__joeli_hat_single:N
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   {
    \__joeli_hat_greek:N #1
   }
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { \str_uppercase:n { #1 } }
     { \widehat{#1} }
     { \amsmathhat{#1} }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__joeli_hat_greek:N
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \c__joeli_hat_greek_clist { #1 }
   { \widehat{#1} }
   { \amsmathhat{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}\hat{A}\hat{b}\hat{B}\hat{\gamma}\hat{\Gamma}\hat{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the standard

[image]

Comment: If you are referring to me then I must edit my answer, since I definitely do *not* recommend it. I just showed a way how to do it.

Comment: Thank you both. But what is the reason against this approach? The full story is that, originally I use either `\hat` or `\widehat` for many letters. Currently I'm experiencing the font package `mtpro2`, which in addition comes with `\what` and `\wwhat` with the width in between `\hat` and `\widehat`. I do not want to modify the document, so that the document works with or without the use of package `mtpro2`. What is the best practice then?

Comment: @campa Not at all! I saw such a recommendation from Mico.